# where clause and matching field in sql

Tags: sql-server

I have a table MyTable in sql server with 3 columns :

```
column1 | column2 | column 3
```

Those 3 columns are typed to nvarchar(128). I am executing the following request:

```
select * from MyTable where column1 = @searchedValue
or column2 = @searchedValue
or column3 = @searchedValue
```

Everything is working well. But I would like to bring the following feature :

Right now, this search is done by an user using an asp.net application where he specify the value to search. He only gets the matching results. But what I would like to bring to those result is an extra field called matchingField (in addition of column1,column2,column3) which will have as a value the name of the column that has matched the where clause.

For example :

If I have this data in db :

```
column1 | column2 | column3
kevin   | spacey  | actor
michael | jordan  | basketball player
```

And as an user I send the value "kev" to search I would like to get :

```
MyResult :
column 1 : kevin
column 2 : spacey
column 3 : actor
matching field : column 1
```

Instead of having only :

```
MyResult :
column 1 : kevin
column 2 : spacey
column 3 : actor
```

Comment: What should happen if more than one column matches? E.g. if you just searched for `e` then columns 1&2 match in the kevin row and columns 1&3 match in the michael row.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CASE WHEN ..`

```
select column1, column2, column3,
        (case when column1 like '%'+@searchedValue+'%'
            then 'column1'
            when column2 like '%'+@searchedValue+'%'
            then 'column2'
            else 'column3' end) as matching_field
from MyTable 
where column1 like '%'+@searchedValue+'%'
or column2 like '%'@searchedValue+'%'
or column3 like '%'@searchedValue+'%'
```

here `matching_field` return the first matching column.

Comment: What happens if more than one column matches?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, here matching_field return the first matching column

Comment: Also the OP wants the input `kev` to match the name `kevin`.  This implies using `LIKE` or maybe even full text search.

Comment: Yes, you are rgt.

Answer (score 0):

First of all maybe do not use or in this query. It can cause a performance issue. Better do it in this way:

```
select *, 'col1' as matching_field from MyTable where column1 = @searchedValue UNION
select *, 'col2' as matching_field from MyTable where column2 = @searchedValue UNION
select *, 'col3' as matching_field from MyTable where column3 = @searchedValue
```

Wit this approach you have column matching_field and in backend code you can count how many matches are equal to col1, col2 and col3.